# Why Linux uses character device interface for /dev/mem?

Tags: linux, memory, devices, block-device

Random Access Memory (RAM) is a block device, why Linux uses a character device file instead of a block device file for user-processes to interface with `/dev/mem`?

```
$ ls -l /dev/mem
crw-r----- 1 root kmem 1, 1 Jul 24 19:05 /dev/mem
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is in the question: RAM isn’t a block device, it can be accessed and modified without constraints (physically) and doesn’t need any buffering.

`/dev/mem` on Linux is handled by [`drivers/char/mem.c`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/char/mem.c) which implements a number of character devices: `/dev/mem`, `/dev/kmem` ([before 5.13](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/drivers/char/mem.c?id=bbcd53c960713507ae764bf81970651b5577b95a)), `/dev/null`, `/dev/port`, `/dev/zero`, `/dev/full`, `/dev/random`, `/dev/urandom` and `/dev/kmsg`.